# What's the typical ration of "employer views" / "search hits"?

Tags: support, jobs

I wrote my resume and made it searchable 1 week ago. So far I got:

> 22 search hits
>   1 employer view

I have a few questions:

- Is this a typical ration? It seems fairly low.. It means that 21 people out of 22 glanced over the short summary of my resume thinking that I wasn't even worth of a look.
- Is 22 search hits typical? My specialty is C++ and the location London UK.

The reason I ask this is to find out whether I just need to wait longer, or if there is something wrong with my resume and I have to rethink it.

I'm asking this question anonymously but my resume is linked to my real accounts on stack exchange, to avoid my current employer from finding out. For the same reason I can't link you my resume.

Comment: Yea I'm wondering too, what happened finally. I made a shortlist and thinking about just applying to them with my careers CV.